# Selecting Data from datagridview and re-inserting selection c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I am trying to select a set of the rows from a datagridview and update it on a click of a button to display only the selected information in the same view, here is the code I have currently:

```
  private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
            rowCollection.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index]); 
        }


        dataset.Tables[0].Clear();


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowCollection)
        {
            DataRow r = dataset.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
            //write the data in the DataRow and then add the datarow in your datatable
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(r);


        }
    }
```

Upon pressing the update button there are no errors and the amount of rows selected is correct, but no information is displayed in the grid view, any help is appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of things happening here:

1. Your second `foreach` loop adds a brand new `DataRow` each iteration.  The row is never populated though - so the `DataGridView` just shows empty rows.
2. Even if you fix this error, `dataset.Tables[0].Clear();` empties the data before you can use it in that same loop.  Each row in `rowCollection` will have `null` data.

To correct this, we'll clone the target `DataTable`.  Then we'll add each row in the `rowCollection` to the cloned table using `DataRowCollection.Add(params object[] values)` instead of `DataRowCollection.Add(DataRow row)`.  After which, we'll clear the target table and merge the clone back into it.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        // Adds the selected rows in order from most recently selected to first selected.
        rowCollection.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index]);

        // Adds the selected rows in order from first selected to most recently selected.
        //rowCollection.Insert(0, dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index]);
    }

    DataTable clone = this.DataSet.Tables[0].Clone();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowCollection)
    {
        object[] values = new object[row.Cells.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            values[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }

        clone.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    this.DataSet.Tables[0].Clear();
    this.DataSet.Tables[0].Merge(clone);
}
```